# How do softwares like Cheat Engine determine what datatype a set of bytes is?

Tags: memory

Cheat engine is a memory hacking tool and it scans the memory of the program to find variables holding in-game data. In the memory scanning section, you can search for a specific data type e.g. arrays or floats etc. depending on your needs.

How does it decide if the set of bytes it is looking at are characters, integers, dwords etc. since every byte can be an integer e.g. the byte 3D can represent a lowercase "a" or it can represent the decimal value of 61.

Comment: It doesn't, that's why you need to specify the data-type: `int` is a 32-bit signed integer, for example.

Answer (score 0):

OS APIs may retrieve the type and size from an address (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65627090/how-cheat-engine-know-what-kind-of-value-is-in-the-memory?rq=2) answer). However, this information can be used for a different purpose, on the application level. For example, encoded. You can use memory as you want, not guaranteeing it's trivially readable as raw.

So it would be more correct to say **it doesn't decide**. You have to specify correctly or make guesses.